# Flask plain SQL without ORM

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a basic CRUD app in Flask and trying to not use any ORM (learning purposes). On my blueprints, I have multiple folders including a **user** folder. I wrote 2 classes in `blueprints/user/models.py`:

- `User`: represent a User entity
- `UserService` : register and login (login is not present yet)

I may move all of my methods from `User` to `UserService` but what I am confused about is where and when to interact with the database. Should I do it directly on my `route.py` vs create a new class?

For instance, to add a new `User` to the database, my SQL should look more or less like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, (email, password))
cursor.fetchall()
conn.commit()
```

**blueprints/user/views.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, jsonify
from prepsmarter.extensions import conn #database connection variable 

user = Blueprint('user', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@user.route('/register')
def login():
    return render_template('register.html')

@user.route('/new-user',methods = ['POST'])
def register_user():
   # where I am going to register a new user
```

**blueprints/user/models.py**

```
class UserService():
    def register_user(self, 
                      email, 
                      password, 
                      registration_date, 
                      active, 
                      sign_in_count, 
                      current_sign_in_on,  
                      last_sign_in_on):
        new_user = User(email, password, registration_date, active, sign_in_count, current_sign_in_on, last_sign_in_on)
        return new_user.__str__()
    

    
class User():
    def __init__(self, email, password, registration_date, active, sign_in_count, current_sign_in_on, last_sign_in_on ):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.registration_date = registration_date
        self.active = active

        # Activity tracking
        self.sign_in_count = sign_in_count
        self.current_sign_in_on = current_sign_in_on
        self.last_sign_in_on = last_sign_in_on

    def desactivate_user(self):
        if self.active == False:
            print(f"User {self.email} is already inactive")
        self.active = False

    def reactive_user(self):
        if self.active == True:
            print(f"User {self.email} is already active")
        self.active = True

    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    def update_activity_tracking(self, ip_address):
        self.sign_in_count += 1
        self.last_sign_in_on = self.current_sign_in_on
        self.current_sign_in_on = datetime.datetime.now()


    def update_password(self, new_password):
        self.password = get_hashed_password(new_password)

    def __str__(self):
        user_attributes = vars(self)
        return (', '.join("%s: %s" % item for item in user_attributes.items()))
```

**Database.py**

```
import pymysql

class Database:
    instance = None 
    
    def __init__(self, host, user, password, db):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self. password = password
        self.db = db 


    def connect(self):
        try: 
            conn = pymysql.connect(
                host = self.host,
                user = self.user,
                passwd = self.password,
                db = self.db
            )
            return conn
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: Ask over at code-review instead

Comment: thanks, I just made a post!